# PHP script to replace cgi script

Tags: php, apache, cgi

I have a CGI script that uses an old database driver that is no longer supported. Instead of struggling with this old cgi script, I thought it would be easier to rewrite it in php. It works now as a php script, but I need it to be served from the same web address. When a user accesses http://somesite.com/myscript.cgi, I want it to run the php script. I tried just renaming the php script with .cgi, but that didn't work. This is on an Apache server hosted by Dreamhost. Any advice?

- Bridger Maxwell

Comment: can you just redirect the cgi script to the php script?

Comment: I am not sure how to set up a redirect... Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Redirect wouldn't be of any use if the CGI was intended to be used as a POST handler. The redirect would be done as a GET and break things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `.htaccess` file with content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myscript.cgi  /myscript.php
```

Read more about [Mod_rewrite](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mod_rewrite) and [examples](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/More_.htaccess_mod_rewrite_examples)

Comment: I'd also add [QSA,L] to the end of the rule.

Comment: Another option would to be do a `<Location /path/to/script.cgi> AddType application/x-httpd-php .cgi </Location>`. I don't know if this would work in a directory marked as a ScriptAlias though